# Is there any JVM that runs on a CBE?

Tags: java, nlp, jvm, uima, playstation3

I'm designing a question-answering system using Apache-UIMA. The system should finally run on a IBM Cell-Broadband-Engine processor(PS3). I'm planning to design the whole thing in Java. But I'm not sure whether Java app could be run on a CBE. Is there any JVM that runs on a CBE?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jikes RVM](http://jikesrvm.org/Home) is known to work on PowerPC architecture, so it should work on the PPE. A quick Google search leads to [Hera JVM](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=132351) which extends JikesRVM to the SPEs for the CELL Architecture. I haven't found any binary available, though

Comment: Hera JVM seems a good option. Any idea about where i could download it?. All I get is some research papers based on it. Couldn't find the actual thing!

Comment: I don't think you can download it directly. Your only option is to write to the author of the paper, to see if they can grant you the right to download it. I haven't heard of any release of Hera JVM. That doesn't mean you can't ask to get it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the PS3 is also a BluRay player, and BluRay mandates some Java under the covers, so there's clearly a JVM in PS3s.  I have no idea how you'd get to it though.  Perhaps exploring the BluRay route might be interesting?  (I warn: have no experience developing against BD-J or PS3 to know if it's too much of a subset.)

Comment: This is true. All Blu-ray Players (including PS3, PS4 and XB1) run JavaME as part of the Blu-ray specification. You can use this to create small homebrew games in Java that runs on all those consoles from the same disc. See http://www.blu-play.com

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this thread is dead, but for people coming after and looking for the same:

I found the HeraJVM code on github. Strange it doesnt show up on google searches.

https://github.com/rmcilroy/HeraJVM

edit:
JikesRVM has been developed further after HeraJVM project, so I would look into Jikes first (last release was in 2016, but last commit is last month).

https://sourceforge.net/projects/jikesrvm/
or
https://github.com/JikesRVM/JikesRVM/

Jikes homepage: https://www.jikesrvm.org/